# Controls in WPF popup sometimes cannot receive input

Tags: c#, wpf, input, popup, treeview

I have a WPF `CheckBox` inside a `Popup`, and I'm finding if it is inside the item template of a `TreeView`, then the `CheckBox` does not respond to user input. If it is outside of the `TreeView`, then there are no problems.

I have created a relatively minimal mock-up here:

https://github.com/logiclrd/TestControlsInPopupsNotWorking

Does anyone know why the `CheckBox` controls popped up from within the `TreeView` cannot be checked?

Comment: Have you done anything to confirm the checkbox isn't getting input (such as create an on click event)? If it isn't getting anything, can you figure out what is getting the click event?

Comment: Well, I can see its style changing when the mouse goes over it, so it _is_ getting _some_ input. I'll put some event handlers on it and see what comes up. One thing that's confusing, though, is that I thought a `Popup` represented effectively a new logical root to the visual tree -- it's a separate top-level window sitting above its owner. Wouldn't that mean that events can't be hooked from further up the tree than the `Popup`? I haven't tested this though.

Comment: When you are debugging in Visual Studio, you can validate your assumption by looking at the Live Visual Tree (might as well check out the Live Property Explorer too). This can be helpful with seeing the full view of the window.

Comment: The Live Visual Tree is useful except for `Popup` elements. It doesn't seem to include them in the tree. I saw the same sequence of events for the `CheckBox` controls that worked and those that didn't: a `PreviewMouseDown` followed by a `PreviewMouseUp`. The handlers for these events evidently mark them as handled, as the main `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` events are not raised.

Comment: I also noticed that `CheckBox` is a subclass of `ToggleButton`, and `TreeView` uses `ToggleButton` internally, so I wondered whether it might be styling `ToggleButton`s, but I ruled that out by putting a `CheckBox` into the `TreeView`'s item template but outside the `Popup` -- that `CheckBox` worked just fine. The `Popup` seems to be an integral part of whatever is causing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is an oversight in the design of the `TreeView`.  Take a look at this:

*Note: Some code excerpts were tidied up to avoid wrapping.*

```
// This method is called when MouseButonDown on TreeViewItem and also listen
// for handled events too.  The purpose is to restore focus on TreeView when
// mouse is clicked and focus was outside the TreeView.  Focus goes either to
// selected item (if any) or treeview itself
internal void HandleMouseButtonDown()
{
    if (!this.IsKeyboardFocusWithin)
    {
        if (_selectedContainer != null)
        {
            if (!_selectedContainer.IsKeyboardFocused)
                _selectedContainer.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            // If we don't have a selection - just focus the TreeView
            this.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

This method is called from `TreeViewItem.OnMouseButtonDown`, which we can see is a class-level handler that's configured to *receive handled events too*:

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(
    typeof(TreeViewItem),
    Mouse.MouseDownEvent,
    new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnMouseButtonDown),
    /* handledEventsToo: */ true);
```

I have verified with the debugger that `Handled` is set to `true` by the time the event makes it to the `TreeViewItem`.

When you press down on the left mouse button over the `CheckBox`, the `CheckBox` begins a speculative 'click' operation and marks the event as handled.  Normally, an ancestor element wouldn't *see* a handled event bubble up, but in this case it explicitly asked for them.

The `TreeView` sees that `this.IsKeyboardFocusWithin` resolves to `false` because the focused element is in another visual tree (the popup).  It then gives focus back to the `TreeViewItem`.

Now, if you look in `ButtonBase`:

```
protected override void OnLostKeyboardFocus(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLostKeyboardFocus(e);

    if (ClickMode == ClickMode.Hover)
    {
        // Ignore when in hover-click mode.
        return;
    }

    if (e.OriginalSource == this)
    {
        if (IsPressed)
        {
            SetIsPressed(false);
        }

        if (IsMouseCaptured)
            ReleaseMouseCapture();

        IsSpaceKeyDown = false;
    }
}
```

We see that `IsPressed` is set to `false` when focus is lost.  If we then go to `OnMouseLeftButtonUp`, we see this:

```
bool shouldClick = !IsSpaceKeyDown && IsPressed && ClickMode == ClickMode.Release;
```

With `IsPressed` now false, the click operation never completes, all because the `TreeViewItem` stole focus away from you when you tried to click the button.

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to work around this, including possibly invoking non-public members of classes, and I haven't been able to come up with anything that works so far. I can't see any way to "unregister" a class handler, which is how `TreeViewItem` hooks the `MouseDown` event. The order of events seems to mean I can't pull off any tricks like trying to convince `TreeView` that `IsKeyboardFocusWithin` is true at the time of the `MouseDown` event -- it looks like it gets the event before I do. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I have logged a bug report for this, which can be "upvoted" if you think it's worthy :-), with the Microsoft Developer Community: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/190202/button-controls-hosted-in-popup-windows-do-not-wor.html

Comment: I also logged it through Microsoft Connect, though I've heard that Microsoft largely ignores Connect these days. Here's the link, for what it's worth: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3146283

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan!  I upvoted both, but I'm not getting my hopes up that anyone will even read them, no less implement a fix ;).

Comment: As a work-around, I have had success so far with using the NuGet library Ryder (which looks like a freely-usable open-source version of Microsoft Detours) to intercept the `HandleMouseButtonDown` method in `TreeView`.

Answer (score 0):

As a work-around, I have had success so far with using the NuGet library Ryder (which looks like a freely-usable open-source (MIT license) version of Microsoft Detours) to intercept the `HandleMouseButtonDown` method in `TreeView`.

The Ryder library can be found in the NuGet library, and the code behind it can be found here:

https://github.com/6A/Ryder

Hooking the `HandleMouseButtonDown` method is pretty simple:

```
        var realMethod = typeof(System.Windows.Controls.TreeView).GetMethod("HandleMouseButtonDown", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var replacementMethod = typeof(Program).GetMethod(nameof(TreeView_HandleMouseButtonDown_shim), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        Redirection.Redirect(realMethod, replacementMethod);
```

The shim that replaces the method can basically do what the real method does but with a fix that detects the cross-visual-tree focus situation:

```
    static void TreeView_HandleMouseButtonDown_shim(TreeView @this)
    {
        // Fix as seen in: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/190202/button-controls-hosted-in-popup-windows-do-not-wor.html
        if (!@this.IsKeyboardFocusWithin)
        {
            // BEGIN NEW LINES OF CODE
            var keyboardFocusedControl = Keyboard.FocusedElement;

            var focusPathTrace = keyboardFocusedControl as DependencyObject;

            while (focusPathTrace != null)
            {
                if (ReferenceEquals(@this, focusPathTrace))
                    return;

                focusPathTrace = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(focusPathTrace) ?? LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(focusPathTrace);
            }
            // END NEW LINES OF CODE

            var selectedContainer = (System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem)TreeView_selectedContainer_field.GetValue(@this);

            if (selectedContainer != null)
            {
                if (!selectedContainer.IsKeyboardFocused)
                    selectedContainer.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                // If we don't have a selection - just focus the treeview
                @this.Focus();
            }
        }
    }
```

Some reflection is needed since this interacts with a private field that is not otherwise exposed from the `TreeView` class, but as work-arounds go, this is a lot less invasive than what I tried at first, which was importing the entirety of the `TreeView` class (and related types) from Reference Source into my project in order to alter the one member. :-)